# How to disable auto test run while building jar file in Spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test, spring-junit

I have created spring boot application for all my repositories&entities. 
I need to disable the auto test run while building jar file because these repositories points to different databases.
Can anyone please help me here ?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you build it? Are you using maven or gradle or another tool?

Comment: I am using maven. I have fixed it by adding property maven.test.skip in pom.xml

Comment: to build your app without running the tests do `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding property in pom.xml

```
<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
```

Comment: This way you disabled the tests for good, which is bad practice. You should instead have the database tests run against an in-memory database so that they don't need access to an external database.

Comment: Can you please provide any sample to accomplish in-memory database?